# Sharepoint in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, spsite

I have been trying to get my MVC C# code to connect to my sharepoint server. I have tried everything and I keep getting this error no matter what I try.

> The Web application at [http://myserver/] could not be found. Verify
>   that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving
>   existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new
>   request URL mapping to the intended application.

This is my code:

```
string strUrl = "http://myserver/";
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(strUrl))
{
}
```

Comment: We're going to need more information than this.  Have you tried adding a new request URL mapping, as the error message states?

Comment: +1 for nickname, wait for some binary code..

Comment: @Robert Yes I have tried URL mapping. I'm am hoping I did it correctly, I am new to this. Also if I type (http://myserver/) into the browser the page will load.

Answer (score 4):

Note that SPSite/SPWeb **only** work on a Server that has SharePoint installed and is part of the Farm. It may work on non-Sharepoint machines, but this is officially unsupported and certain operations may throw exceptions.

Generally, external connectivity to SharePoint is done through [Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee705814.aspx) or (since 2010) through the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537247.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx) to connect (assuming you are using SharePoint 2010).  If you want to use the server object model (which you are using in your code sample), the MVC app will need to be running on the same server that SharePoint is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you target your binary as 64-bit with .Net framework 3.5, otherwise it will throw this error. Also as other answers has stated; to use the object model like this require that the code is executed on a server in the farm.

Comment: I have tried to use .NET 3.5 and set the target as 64-bit, but when I do I get a bunch of errors and I cannot compile. Also, I am running my code on the server that way I can use the server object model. None of these fixes will fix my problem.

Comment: Ok, but until you manage to compile and run your code 64-bit, 3.5, your error will continue.
What kind of error are you getting when trying to compile?

Comment: Some of the dll's cannot compile to 64bit.